# How can I renew my sample() in an ifelse statement?

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this.

```
   investor_name funding_round_type count
   <chr>         <chr>              <int>
 1 .406 Ventures angel                  1
 2 .406 Ventures other                  2
 3 .406 Ventures private-equity         1
 4 .406 Ventures series-a               5
 5 .406 Ventures series-b               2
 6 .406 Ventures series-c+              7
 7 .406 Ventures venture                1
 8 500 Startups  angel                 40
```

I would like to replace all the instances where `funding_round_type` is equal to `venture` and replace it with either `series-a`, `series-b` or `series-c+`. I'd like to randomly select one of those with a 40% chance for either of the first two and a 20% for the last one.

```
my_df %>% 
   mutate(funding_round_type = ifelse(funding_round_type == "venture", 
                                      sample(c("series-a", "series-b", "series-c"), 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.4, .4, .2)),
                                      funding_round_type))
```

Weirdly, the `sample()` seems to choose once and then revert to the chosen value for every row. I've run this a few times and it replaces `venture` with only one of the values from my list of options and doesn't include any instances of any of the other values.

How can I get sample() to run fresh on every row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `ifelse` runs the `sample` function only once and you are selecting one value from it which is recycled for every other value. Try doing

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>% 
  mutate(funding_round_type = ifelse(funding_round_type == "venture", 
        sample(c("series-a", "series-b", "series-c"), 
        sum(funding_round_type == "venture"),replace = TRUE, prob = c(.4, .4, .2)), 
        funding_round_type))
```

Or with `replace`

```
my_df %>% 
   mutate(funding_round_type = replace(funding_round_type, 
   funding_round_type == "venture", sample(c("series-a", "series-b", "series-c"), 
   sum(funding_round_type == "venture"), replace = TRUE, prob = c(.4, .4, .2))))
```

Also you can replace this directly, without any `ifelse` or any packages.

```
my_df$funding_round_type[my_df$funding_round_type == "venture"] <-  
    with(my_df, sample(c("series-a", "series-b", "series-c"), 
    sum(funding_round_type == "venture"), replace = TRUE, prob = c(.4, .4, .2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rowwise()` will resample for each row:

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(funding_round_type = if_else(
    funding_round_type == "venture",
    sample(c("series-a", "series-b", "series-c+"), 1, prob = c(.4, .4, .2)),
    funding_round_type))
```

Also - minor, but you don't need `replace=TRUE` since you're only pulling one sample per call to `sample()`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[funding_round_type == "venture", funding_round_type := 
    sample(c("series-a", "series-b", "series-c+"), 1, prob = c(.4, .4, .2))][]
#    investor_name funding_round_type count
#1: .406 Ventures              angel     1
#2: .406 Ventures              other     2
#3: .406 Ventures     private-equity     1
#4: .406 Ventures           series-a     5
#5: .406 Ventures           series-b     2
#6: .406 Ventures          series-c+     7
#7: .406 Ventures           series-b     1
#8:  500 Startups              angel    40
```

---

Or using `case_when` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyerse)
df %>%
     mutate(funding_round_type = case_when(funding_round_type == "venture" ~ 
        sample(c("series-a", "series-b", "series-c+"), 1, prob = c(.4, .4, .2)),
       TRUE ~ funding_round_type))
#  investor_name funding_round_type count
#1 .406 Ventures              angel     1
#2 .406 Ventures              other     2
#3 .406 Ventures     private-equity     1
#4 .406 Ventures           series-a     5
#5 .406 Ventures           series-b     2
#6 .406 Ventures          series-c+     7
#7 .406 Ventures           series-a     1
#8  500 Startups              angel    40
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(investor_name = c(".406 Ventures", ".406 Ventures", 
".406 Ventures", ".406 Ventures", ".406 Ventures", ".406 Ventures", 
".406 Ventures", "500 Startups"), funding_round_type = c("angel", 
"other", "private-equity", "series-a", "series-b", "series-c+", 
"venture", "angel"), count = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 40L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: What's the difference between case_when and if else?

Comment: @tadon11Aaa `case_when` does type checks

Comment: what is a type check?

Comment: @tadon11Aaa  It means, that when if you provide different class elements, it would show error `case_when(1:5  == 3~ "hello", TRUE ~ 1)` and `case_when(1:5  == 3~ "hello", TRUE ~ "not hello")`